# My Custom Webfont is not being rendered in any browser

Tags: html, css

Please help fix my codes.
My custom font doesn't seem to be rendering on any browser i open.

Here's my CSS code.

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'Guildford';
src: url('../fonts/guildford_pro_titling-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
src: url('../fonts/guildford_pro_titling-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
src: url('../fonts/guildford_pro_titling-webfont.eot') format(embedded-opentype),
src: url('../fonts/guildford_pro_titling.otf') format('opentype') !Important;}

body {
font-family: 'Guildford', sans-serif;
background-image: url(../img/staropaquebackground.png);
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you don't need the `src` on every line when you're comma separating the urls.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'Guildford';
src: url('../fonts/guildford_pro_titling-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/guildford_pro_titling-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('../fonts/guildford_pro_titling-webfont.eot') format(embedded-opentype),
url('../fonts/guildford_pro_titling.otf') format('opentype') !important;
}

body {
font-family: 'Guildford', sans-serif;
background-image: url(../img/staropaquebackground.png);
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

You need to basically replace commas with semicolons and remove multiple 'src:' declarations.
I would recommend any code editor with code validation, to avoid such problems in the future.

[image]

Comment: No. You're now *redeclaring* `src` instead of specifying multiple values for it.

Comment: Thanks, But it still didn't call up the font.

Comment: @EdwardBella Also make sure that your path is pointing to your font files.

Answer (score 0):

You have errors that would be picked up if you [used a validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator).

Look at [the example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40font-face):

> ```
> @font-face {
>  font-family: "Open Sans";
>  src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
>         url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
> }
> ```

Don't specify `src:` before every URL.

The property name must be mentioned only once.

It is then followed by a comma-separated list of values.